# Directory access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm writing web application using codeigniter framework. Here is the structure of document root

```
application
system
website
```

What I want is that only the website directory to be accessаble. Here is the content of .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteRule .* /website/%1 [QSA]
```

When I type the site url in browser I'm redirected to website dir. So far, so good. It works.
The problem comes when I try to access a dir within the website directory. I get

```
404 page not found
```

What to do so the directories below the website dir to be accessаble ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rule you need:

```
RewriteRule (?!^website(/.*|)$)^.*$ website%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: That works, but is it possible the url to looks like http://foobar.com/assets where assets is dir below the website dir. With the code you suggest I get http://foobar.com/website/ when I try to access http://foobar.com and http://foobar.com/website/assets/

Comment: Yes it is possible by removing `R` flag, please check my edited answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^website
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I get "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace"